# Run a desktop environment from a docker container

Tags: 16.04, docker

I have a headless ubuntu server (16.04) at home and i have few desktop environments (one for work, one for pet projects) in docker containers that i connect to though XRDP and it works perfectly fine, though i'm wondering if it is also possible to run those environments locally but still from the docker container on the server itself if i connect it to a monitor

My goal is to create two aliases each would start one of the desktop environment; from what i read it's possible to run GUI apps on a running desktop environment by sharing the X11 socket but i'm not sure about running a complete desktop environment from a headless server.

Comment: As I understand, your "headless server" has no X server running and no DE installed, so you cannot run X applications locally.

Comment: Would it be possible to run an x server and start the desktop environment that resides in docker this way ?